# spring-boot property placeholder

Tags: properties, configuration, spring-boot

I'm not able to figure out why I am not able to inject values into my application.properties file in spring-boot.  external property into the logging.file variable. I have an application.properties file which looks like this

```
logging.file=${mylogfile}
server.port=${myport}
```

with corresponding Spring-boot Application class

```
@PropertySources({
@PropertySource("file:///c:/myfolder/externalprops.properties"),
})

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

and external property file

```
mylogfile=myoutput.log
myport=8060
```

When I run my spring-boot 1.0.2.REL application I get the following exception every time I try to inject mylogfile into the logging.file property in application.properties

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mylogfile' in string value "${mylogfile}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
```

Note that I am not having any problems injecting and starting up the application if I  inject the server port number on its own.

I am going around in circles on this issue and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `@PropertySource` to inject values into "application.properties" - the latter has to be parsed and ready to use before any `@Configuration` is read, or even known about. Your external properties could go in "${user.dir}/application.properties" and I think that would achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: I gathered that I must do something wrong. What makes me confused is that I am able to inject the server port using this approach. Hence the reason I am banging my head against the wall and trying to do the same for the logging.file. don't understand why injecting the port work but not injecting the logfile

Comment: It's about the order. Logging has to be set up before the `ApplicationContext` is created. If you like you can re-initialize the logging yourself from your app and switch output files after logging has started (we think it's better to do it once by default).